# timestamps fields stored as per my local timezone but retrieved with shift -3 hours in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, timestamp-with-timezone

I have a problem with  `created_at`, `updated_at` fields in a laravel project.

I have to set a timezone setting in `app.php` to *'Asia/Baghdad'*.

when i create a new record, it's stored correctly as per my *local-time*, but when i fetch the data those fields returned with shift -3 hours.

check attached pictures please:
[image: in storing case]

[image: in retrieving case]

Answer (score 0):

By default Mysql convert TIMESTAMP to UTC before store.
So, Don't worry about it. You'll need to focus less on the database.
You can set time zone on each language or framework to get the correct time value.
data will vary drastically depending on language.

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html

```
MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval. (This does not occur for other types such as DATETIME.) By default, the current time zone for each connection is the server's time. The time zone can be set on a per-connection basis. As long as the time zone setting remains constant, you get back the same value you store.
```

Thanks, hope it'll help you

Comment: as i said, i have problem in fetching not in storing